# Setting ntp time from gpsd

Tags: linux, ntp, time-synchronization, gps

I'm trying to configure ntpd to source it's time from a gps receiver (`BU-353S4`) but I'm getting some errors.

I'm using ntpd 4.2.8.p6-3 and gpsd 3.16-2 on Arch Linux Arm. I've been following the [tutorial on the arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_Time_Protocol_daemon#Using_ntpd_with_GPS) but it doesn't have any troubleshooting information.

The gpsd log contains the entry

`gpsd:ERROR: response: {"class":"ERROR","message":"No such device as /dev/gps0"}\x0d\x0a`

Repeated every 6 seconds or so, nothing else other than start, stop messages.

/var/log/ntp.log contains:

```
Listen and drop on 0 v6wildcard [::]:123
Listen and drop on 1 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1:123
Listen normally on 3 eth0 172.10.10.75:123
Listen normally on 4 lo [::1]:123
Listen normally on 5 eth0 [fe80::ba27:ebff:feba:af05%2]:123
Listening on routing socket on fd #22 for interface updates
GPSD_JSON(0): GPSD revision=3.16 release=3.16 protocol=3.11
```

`ntpq -p` outputs

```
    remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 GPSD_JSON(0)    .GPS.            0 l    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

`/etc/ntp.conf` contains

```
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1

restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery

# GPSD config
server 127.127.46.0
fudge 127.127.46.0 time1 0.0 time2 0.0 refid GPS

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
logfile /var/log/ntp.log
```

However `sudo gpscat /dev/gps0` outputs (to my untrained eye) valid nmea gps information, and `cgps` and `gpsmon` all get a fix and output useful information.

`/dev/ttyUSB0` has permissions `crw-rw---- 1 root uucp 188`.
`gpsd` is running under user `nobody` and `ntpd` is running as user `ntp`

Comment: What are the permissions on `/dev/gps0`?  If those look OK, is there any chance selinux is confusing matters?

Comment: `ls -l /dev/gps0` returns `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Mar 30 10:36 /dev/gps0 -> ttyUSB0` I haven't changed those, it's what gpsd creates it with.

Comment: The permissions on soft links are ignored; what are the permissions on the target, and what user is the daemon that errors running as?  Also, selinux?

Comment: `crw-rw---- 1 root uucp 188, 0 Mar 30 10:40 /dev/ttyUSB0` 

I'm not running selinux

Comment: Please stop answering only part of the question - this will go quicker if you answer in full each time!  What user is the daemon that logs the errors you quote (`gpsd`) running as?

Comment: `gpsd` is running as `nobody`, `ntp` is running as `ntp`.

Answer (score 2):

`gpsd` is running as nobody, and so doesn't have privilege to read `/dev/ttyUSB0`, which is exactly what it's complaining about.

If you add the `nobody` user to the group `uucp`, that should fix things, but it's not recommended.  Or you can change the modes on `/dev/ttyUSB0` to be 666, which is slightly less dreadful.  Best of all would be to edit the `gpsd` startup config so it runs as some other user, possibly `gpsd`, and make `/dev/ttyUSB0` group-owned by `gpsd`'s primary group (also probably `gpsd`).

Assuming that `gpsd` sets the time once it can read the GPS correctly, this will enable `ntpd` to advertise the time, knowing (since you have configured it) that it's got it from a stratum-0 (ntp) source.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful that you must "run gpsd on that linked `/dev/gps0` so that the GPSD_JSON line appears as expected". So check whether your GPSD run on `/dev/gps0` or not. My GPSD run on `/dev/ttyS0` on my server and after I change the DEVICES to `/dev/gps0` in `/etc/default/gpsd`, NTPd can link GPSD successfully.